# CSS menu issue with hover

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

On my css menu here [My site](http://www.touchoflunacy.com)  I can't seem to get the menu to match up on all levels no matter how much I have tweaked the code. I am a CSS newbie so I am likely missing something but when you hover and mouse down there are three different sizes and I want them all to be uniform. I have looked at it in chrome and firebug, but can't find the parent menu to expand to match the hover.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is totally messed up. For starters dont set the width of the  in the submenu. Instead set the width of the whole UL.submenu, and make the  inside display:block, so that they will fill thew whole width

Comment: i agree with @dbugger - pretty messy, it would take quite some time to provide you with an answer... i'd start by cleaning everything up: 1/ put each property on it's own line, so you keep an overview, 2/ make sure you *never* change margin or padding on hover, just set bgcolor + text-decoration - nothing else, 3/ put margin/padding always on the a, never on the li - that should get you in the right direction...

Comment: Yeah I got a template and while it has helped a ton by pointing me in right direction some of the CSS is just evil.

Comment: Sorry, its too messed up. Delete all the styles from the submenu and start over. It will be better in the long run.

Comment: Dont set "width" of anything with "hover", thats a rule you should ALWAYS follow.

Answer (score 0):

change this in your css:

```
#menu2 li li a, #menu2 li li a:link, #menu2 li li a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    width: 160px; //this is the change (width decreased)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to implement a [hover menu using CSS](http://shingokko.com/blog-entry/pure-css-hover-menu.html). It works in all modern browsers, but doesn't work in IE6 as it doesn't support :hover on li tags.